# c++ algorithm modulus

Tags: c++, c, algorithm

How could I easily check whether `a <= b <= a+c`, modulus 256 (where we take the values for `a` and `a+c` that are the closest to `b`) ?

basically I am in a situation similar to the one found in TCP. TCP expects to receive a sequence number (`b`) that is not less than what it has last received (`a`), but no greater than what it has last received + an offset (`c`). The problem is that all of this occurs with modulus (in the case of TCP, it's mod 32535, and in mine, mod 256).

Sorry if it's not clear, feel free to ask for details and I'll update the question.

Comment: What do you know about `c`?  Is it less than 128?  Right now, I'm guessing this is a problem like finding whether two compass headings are within 5 degrees of each other (though that would be modulo 360 degrees), but it seems underconstrained.

Comment: ArjunShankar: I edited the question to reflect your suggestions.
Justin: basically I am in a situation similar to the one found in TCP. TCP expects to receive a sequence number that is not less than what it has last received, but no greater than what it has last received + 10, for example. The problem is that all of this occurs with modulus (in the case of TCP, it's 32000, but in mine, 256).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple C function to do this would be:

```
int is_valid (int old_val, int new_val, int offset, int width)
{
  if (new_val <= old_val)
    /* The only way this can happen is if there was wrap-around.
    OR if the `new_val' is invalid. If it is invalid, the next `if'
    will catch it.  */
    new_val += width;

  if (new_val > (old_val + offset))
    return 0;

  return 1;
}
```

It is easy to understand, and I think that's what really matters.

In your case: `offset = 10` and `width = 256`.

**CAVEATS:**

1. Inputs should be small enough that `new_val + width` and `old_val + offset` fit in an `int`.
2. If `old_val` and `new_val` are same, the input is considered invalid. If this is not what you want, change `<=` to `<`.
3. The function assumes that `old_val` and `new_val` are already modulo-width, i.e. modulo-256. It doesn't verify this.

When I run it with the following inputs:

```
int main (void)
{
  printf ("%d\n", is_valid (255, 9, 10, 256)); /* Pass.  */
  printf ("%d\n", is_valid (255, 10, 10, 256)); /* Fail.  */
  printf ("%d\n", is_valid (0, 10, 10, 256)); /* Pass.  */
  printf ("%d\n", is_valid (0, 11, 10, 256)); /* Fail.  */
  printf ("%d\n", is_valid (100, 109, 10, 256)); /* Pass.  */
  printf ("%d\n", is_valid (100, 110, 10, 256)); /* Pass.  */
  printf ("%d\n", is_valid (100, 111, 10, 256)); /* Fail.  */

  return 0;
}
```

It gives the following output:

```
1
0
1
0
1
1
0
```

Comment: This answer seems interesting. It is however difficult for me to see whether the answer corresponds to the question I asked, because if I could really see whether it's ok or not, I don't think I would have needed to ask it in the first place. So can someone please confirm that it answers the original question ?

Comment: @bob - If after looking at the code, you're still unsure whether it *does what you want*, you should consider asking for a clearer specification from whoever described the required functionality. Anyway, I attached a few test runs. See for yourself.

Answer (score 0):

```
template <int N> bool moduloLess (int a, int b)
{
  // this is a group, even after modulo!
  int d=(b+N-a)%N;
  // use the representative in [-N/2-1, N/2] and check whether its greater
  // negative means that b was "smaller"
  // since we got the representative in [0, N-1], check whether we are greater than N/2 
  return d*2 <= N;  
}
```

This should do it, if I got your question right...

For your updated question: it should work if you just use `moduloLess<256>(b-a, c)`, at least if c is smaller than 128.

Comment: I edited my question a few seconds ago to try to make it clearer. I don't know if I succeeded. I basically want the same thing as what TCP does. Does your answer do that ?

Answer (score 0):

For a monotonic counter or timer with rollover, to decide if `a` is a bit greater than `b`, modulo 256, you can just check if `a - b < 128 (mod 256)`.

Examples where a > b:

```
256 - 206 = 50 (mod 256)
  0 - 206 = 50 (mod 256)
 20 - 226 = 50 (mod 256)
```

Examples where a < b:

```
206 - 256 = 206 (mod 256)
206 -   0 = 206 (mod 256)
226 -  20 = 206 (mod 256)
```

The only trick is that the `%` operator in C can give negative results.  A better way would be to cast to a 1-byte type (`unsigned char` or `uint8_t`, perhaps).

So for your case, the test would be:

```
if ((unsigned char)(b - a) < 128 && (unsigned char)(a + c - b) < 128)
```

Answer (score 0):

Define a macro like:

```
#define COMPARE_MODULUS (a,b,c)  ((a)%256) <= ((b) % 256)? ((b) <= ((a)+(c))?true:false):false
```